# Working with data in quoted fields with GNU AWK

Tags: csv, awk, text

My apologies if this has been asked before. I've looked but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

I have this sample file, test.csv:

`"abc","def,apple","2019-10-10"`

I'd like to output any of the first fields based on the date in the last one. I've tried this

`gawk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '($3 >= "2018-10-10") {print $1}' test.csv`

but the output is empty.

If I remove the quotes around the date in test.csv, the above works. The command outputs "abc". I have a long file that follows the above pattern and I'm sure I can use a simple regex to remove the quotes around the dates, but is there a way to avoid this by changing the above gawk command?

Comment: Since you are already using gawk, add `gensub` to the condition to remove the quotes only in the comparison: `(gensub(/^"|"$/,"","g",$3) >= "2019-10-10")`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! I'm glad to have learned about "gensub"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$3` is `"2019-10-10"`, i.e. with quotes included, so you need to include quotes in the string you're comparing it to:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '($3 >= "\"2018-10-10\"") {print $1}' test.csv
"abc"
```

The difference between this and a solution that just works by setting FS is it'll continue to work if/when you need to operate on fields other than the last field  even if some of your fields contain commas (`,`) or escaped quotes (`""`). Try all the solutions if your input was:

```
$ cat test.csv
"abc","very,""bad"",field","2019-10-10","other,""bad"",field."
```

```
$ gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '($3 >= "\"2018-10-10\"") {print $1}' test.csv
"abc"
```

You probably really want to pass the target date as a variable though so here's how I'd really write this:

```
$ gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' -v tgt='"2018-10-10"' '$3 >= tgt {print $1}' test.csv
"abc"
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I really just used the quote escaping and left everything else the same so that I could work with fields other than the last one. Still, I didn't know one could pass the date as a variable. I will certainly use that in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk -F ',' '$NF >= "\"2018-10-10\""{ print $1 }' test.csv
```

or

```
awk -F '"' '$(NF-1) >= "2018-10-10"{ print $2 }' test.csv
```

`$NF` contains last column

Comment: Thank you! This works! It seems that all I needed was to know how to escape the quotes. I'm using your first solution.

Comment: My apologies. I changed the accepted answer to the another one, since it gives the exact answer needed and is more general than yours. (Yours works only on the last field.) Still, it is useful. Many thanks again!